# latex problem what is wrong with \ less

Tags: bug, mathjax

the \less latex symbol doesn't show properly in firefox . (it is in the latex A4 manual table 97) example $  \forall x \exists y (x \less y) $

Or am I making a simple mistake (would not be the first time)

Comment: `\less` doesn't appear to be among the [$\LaTeX$ symbols supported by MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#l).  Moreover, the [Comprehensive $\LaTeX$ Symbol List](http://zelmanov.ptep-online.com/ctan/symbols-a4.pdf) indicates that it is part of the `MnSymbol` package.  What's wrong with simply using `$<$` to produce $<$?

Comment: @ArthurFischer thanks that is new the list you mention isn't mentioned on http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference i just always thought that all Tex from the symbol list was available, should we adjust the tutorial?

Comment: If you want to use a \ expression for $<$, try `$\lt$`.

Comment: @Willemien: symbols-a4.pdf is "The Comprehensive $\LaTeX$ Symbol List" of glyphs available from many packages. MathJax supports some of the packages, but not all. On math.SE, the "TeX-AMS_HTML-full" configuration is used, which includes most of the AMS symbols. Including more packages imposes a larger overhead on each user, and there does not seem to be a great need for more (except for those who would like commutative diagrams).

Comment: @robjohn thanks, I was just unaware of that (it is not in the tutorial, or did i mis something?)

Comment: Just use `$<$` to make $<$. On the other hand, if you want to make $\le$ (less than or equal sign), use `$\le$`.

Comment: Using `$<$` can sometimes confuse the system, since < also signals an HTML tag.  If you always follow < with a space, you should be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was given by [Daniel R](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12838/latex-problem-what-is-wrong-with-less#comment50321_12838) in the comment. Expanding it a bit:  you can use

- `$\lt$` and `$\gt$` for $\lt$ and $\gt$.
- `$\le$` and `$\ge$` for $\le$ and $\ge$. Or  `$\leq$` and `$\geq$` for the same effect.

[Full list of LaTeX-supported symbols is here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands).

---

As an aside, I will [sort of] answer [Arthur Fisher's comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12838/latex-problem-what-is-wrong-with-less#comment50318_12838) by copying it from the HTML source of this page:

What's wrong with simply using `$&lt;$` to produce $&lt;$?